# Dump Microsoft Word text without looping

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to dump every word and their start range and end range into an array or dictionary or etc. without looping?

I already tried the following two methods and they work,

```
Sub test_1()
Dim wrd As Variant
Dim TxtArray() As String
Dim i As Long

For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Range.Words
'code to add to add to array her
Next
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub test_2()
Dim TxtArray() As String
TxtArray = Split(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
End Sub
```

The split method can't give me the option to register the starting and ending range positions of each word, because I may want to highlight them later on; plus when I add words to the dictionary, I eliminate the duplicate ones

Is there a way to dump the `Range.Words` collection without looping? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Why is looping not an option?

Comment: Registering the starting and ending range positions (numbers) is not a robust way to code Word. These index values are not reliable due to the non-visible and non-printing characters in the text flow. You could have an array or collection of Range objects, or you could set bookmarks.

Comment: @Dirk , i don't want to use loop to test performance against looping method., i'm storing these values _(word, start of word,end of word)_ in an array or dictionary where each **word** is unique and i'm doing this for later processing For example highlighting some of then ...etc

Comment: To answer your literal question, whether it's possible to get the Range.Words collection without looping AND also access the Start and End properties: NO IT IS NOT. Not only that, but the idea of storing the Start and End points as integer values is not reliable.

Comment: Dear Cindy Meister, thanks for the answer. The idea of doing this is as follows: I store in a dictionary the words of a document which has a list of words, and I also store in another dict. all the words (no duplicates) of another document, then I compare the two dictionaries by going through each “key” in the second dict. and check if it exists in the first dict., then I want to highlight the words (keys) that are found in the second dict. but not in the first one.  I needed a fast way to indicate the start and end of each of those words for highlighting, hence the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

"when I add words to the dictionary, I eliminate the duplicate ones" - you don't have to do that: use an array of ranges as the value for the dictionary, with the word as the key.

For example:

```
Sub MapWords()

    Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim wrd As Variant, tmp, ub As Long, txt As String, w

    Dim i As Long

    For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Range.Words
        txt = Trim(wrd.Text)
        If Len(txt) > 1 Then
            If Not d.Exists(txt) Then
                d.Add txt, GetArray(wrd)
            Else
                tmp = d(txt)
                ub = UBound(tmp) + 1
                ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To ub)
                Set tmp(ub) = wrd
                d(txt) = tmp
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'e.g. -
    Set w = d("split")(1)
    Debug.Print w.Text, w.Start, w.End

End Sub

Function GetArray(wrd)
    Dim rv(1 To 1)
    Set rv(1) = wrd
    GetArray = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Tim Williams.. I am aware of that BUT the goal here is not to use any kind of loop to get each word into another variable for later use

Comment: I thought your goal was to put the words into a collection/dictionary for analysis?  What does it matter if a loop is involved or not?

Comment: Speed optimization

Comment: Is the loop performance poor?  What size are your documents ?  I did only test with a small example...